# Provide data for gwteventservice from different service

Tags: web-services, gwt, comet, server-push, gwt-eventservice

I am trying to push data from my services to the browser with gwteventservice, but I am not able to do it from a different service then from **MyServiceImpl.java**.
Here is the situtation: I have service **DifferentService.java** that reads data from client. Then I have class **MyServiceImpl.java**, which represents server side of **MyService.java** (clasic gwt project structure). Finally I have class **CallEvent.java** which uses **addEvent** method to send data to a listener (gwteventservice stuff). When I instantiate a **CallEvent** class within **MyServiceImpl.java** and call proper method (**addEvent**) a message is succesfully delivered to a listener. When I call same code from **DifferentService.java** class nothing happend (no message is delivered to a listener).
I think this is a classic situation, when data need to be send from some data provider to a client utilizing gwteventservice.
Could you please help me finding a problem? Which solution or approach do you use in such situations?
Here are my code snippets used for data delivery.

MsgEvent.java (represents message carrying data - gwteventstuff)

```
public class MsgEvent implements Event {

    public static final Domain SERVER_MESSAGE_DOMAIN = DomainFactory.getDomain("my_domain");
    public String message;

    public MsgEvent(){}

    public MsgEvent(String message) {
            this.setMessage(message);
    }

    public String getMessage() {
            return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
    }
}
```

CallEvent.java (gwteventstuff)

```
public class CallEvent extends RemoteEventServiceServlet{
    public void SendData(String data){
           //create the event
           Event theEvent = new MsgEvent("DagaMsg");
           //add the event, so clients can receive it
           addEvent(MsgEvent.SERVER_MESSAGE_DOMAIN, theEvent);
}
}
```

DifferentService.java

```
 public class DifferentService{
 ...
 //Reading string data from client
 CallEvent ce = new CallEvent();
 ce.SendData(stringData);        //this code delivers nothing to a listener
 ...
 }
```

MyServiceImpl.java (gwt stuff)

```
 public class MyServiceImpl extends RemoteEventServiceServlet implements MyService {
     public void sendMessage(String message) {
          CallEvent ce = new CallEvent();
          ce.SendData("Data");     //this code deliver message succesfully to a listener
     }
 }
```

web.xml (gwt and gwteventservice stuff)

```
<web-app>
    <!-- Default page to serve -->
    <welcome-file-list>
         <welcome-file>My.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>cz.pohanka.my.server.MyServiceImpl</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>MyService</servlet-name>
         <url-pattern>/cz.pohanka.my.My/MyService</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet> 
         <servlet-name>EventService</servlet-name> 
         <servlet-class>de.novanic.eventservice.service.EventServiceImpl</servlet-class> 
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>   
         <servlet-name>EventService</servlet-name> 
         <url-pattern>/cz.pohanka.my.My/gwteventservice</url-pattern> 
    </servlet-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

I hope I have included everything important.
I think that problem could be in web.xml.
What do you think.
Thank you.

Pavel

Answer (score 0):

I know the question was asked several months ago, but maybe it can help someone...

In your `DifferentService`, you can't create a servlet with `new CallEvent()` to send your event...

Instead, use something like:

```
EventExecutorServiceFactory pushServiceFactory = EventExecutorServiceFactory.getInstance();
EventExecutorService pushService = pushServiceFactory.getEventExecutorService( /* param */);
pushService.addEvent(...);
```

Replace `param` either by the `HttpServletRequest` or by a client id.